# Suddenly come up Line feed code in worksheet

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Suddenly came up Line feed code in all editor like

```
<<q
```

[image]

How can I hide it?

Product ID: oracle.sqldeveloper
Product Version: 19.1.0.094.2042

Comment: How can you hide what, exactly? You misspelled from so the parser doesn't like your code, and the underlined text indicates where that happens

Comment: Oh you mean the whitespace characters...it's a preference under Code Editor, Display, show whitespace characters

Comment: It works! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preferences - Code Editor - Display - Show Whitespace Characters

[image]

Useful for when you're wondering if that's a CR or a CR/LF or a tab vs 5 spaces...